# I can't seem to install VIM on Spyder with conda, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: github, installation, vim, conda

This doesn't work for me on macOS. ---> conda install spyder-vim -c spyder-ide

"conda install spyder-vim -c spyder-ide
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

- spyder-vim

Current channels:

- https://conda.anaconda.org/spyder-ide/osx-64
- https://conda.anaconda.org/spyder-ide/noarch
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/osx-64
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/osx-64
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
- https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/osx-64
- https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

```
https://anaconda.org
```

and use the search bar at the top of the page."

Answer (score 0):

Although [the documentation](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder-vim#installation) implies it once was hosted on the **spyder-ide** channel, looking at [the actual channel](https://anaconda.org/spyder-ide/repo) indicates it was deleted. That plugin hasn't been updated (or tested) in approaching two years.

Only option looks like trying to install through PyPI:

```bash
pip install spyder-vim
```

### Commentary

I strongly recommend creating a dedicated environment for Spyder and loading Conda Python environments as Spyder kernels. I've (anecdotally) observed that users who install infrastructure, such as Spyder or Jupyter, directly in their environments (especially in **base**) tend to have increasingly degraded and frustrating experiences.